unable to do any connection after changing hostname(probably)
I needed to change hostname on ubuntu 22.04. I did it the old way, by manually editing /etc/hostname and adding
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   my-host-name

into /etc/hosts not knowing about hostnamectl. It surely might be something else as well, but I'm not aware of it. Just reinstalled yesterday, and this morning nothing dns-related works.
I can ping, or do ssh connection using ip. I can print on local network, but it's exceptionally slow. Trying dig -t a google.com prints communications error to 10.128.32.11
I already tried:

hostnamectl set-hostname my-host-name
systemctl restart NetworkManager
resolvectl flush-caches
systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service

during this, I noticed, that resolvectl dns returns some global dns servers I didn't asked for. That's probably the reason, not sure. Can anyone advice how to fix?
(note: company uses some super-obsoleted vpn provided, which requires NetworkManager, that's why I was working with that in first place)

Forgot to check /etc/resolv.conf. Vpn service crashed probably, and there was wrong data here. Cleaning this file, flushing caches fix this issue. Sorry for spamming, figure this out myself by luck just moments after submitting question.
